# Why does change of a substring take no effect on string it subtracted from?

Tags: swift, string, substring

I'm still new to Swift and read language guide from Apple.

When it comes to String chapter about substring, I've got a question about content variation of substring. When I change the substring without converting it to String, the original string shall be changed as well while it is not.

[image]

as you may see from explanation of how substring comes from, substring hold a reference to part of string storage. Manipulating of substring shall take effect on String content if substring is not explicitly converted to a String.

here is code describes the question

```
var originalString = "hello, world!"
var varSubString = originalString[..<originalString.index(originalString.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)]
print(varSubString)
//print "hell"
varSubString.insert("a", at: varSubString.endIndex)
print(varSubString)
//print "hella"
print(originalString)
//print "hello, world!", but expected to print "hella, world"
```

Comment: Because substring is a new object after all.

Comment: Google "Copy on write".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that if you change substring or original string they won't be a reference anymore.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

> This performance optimization means you don’t have to pay the
>   performance cost of copying memory until you modify either the string
>   or substring

Be careful ususing substring for long time

> Storing substrings may, therefore, prolong the lifetime of string data
>   that is no longer otherwise accessible, which can appear to be memory
>   leakage.

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
var mySubstring = str[..<index] // Hello

print(str) // Hello
print(mySubstring) // Hello, playground

str = "Hallo, playground"

print(str) //Hallo, playground
print(mySubstring) //Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Apple document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) on Substring and String optimization.

> Like strings, each substring has a region of memory where the
>   characters that make up the substring are stored. The difference
>   between strings and substrings is that, as a performance optimization,
>   a substring can reuse part of the memory that’s used to store the
>   original string, or part of the memory that’s used to store another
>   substring. (Strings have a similar optimization, but if two strings
>   share memory, they are equal.) **This performance optimization means
>   you don’t have to pay the performance cost of copying memory until you
>   modify either the string or substring.**

All these optimizations are applicable until either string or substring is modified. If it is modified, string ans substring will be a separate objects.